# Calculating average through pig script

Tags: apache-pig

```
/*calculating average for itemssold(int) grouped by city */

a = LOAD 'sales.txt' USING PigStorage(','); /*loading sales data and it has 50 fields that are comma separated*/ 
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $3 as city:chararray, $4 as itemssold:int;/*defining schema for needed fields*/
c = GROUP b BY city; /*grouping by city*/
d = FOREACH c GENERATE group,AVG(b.itemssold); /*calculating average*/
dump d; /*writing output*/
```

Here i am trying to calculate the average on itemssold grouped by city.

> Error: Error while computing Average.

Can anyone please help me fixing this error?

Note: Since sales.txt has 50 fields separated by comma, i don't want to define schema for all the fields while loading sales.txt into relation itself.

Comment: What does dump b look like?Column indexes start from $0.Are you sure city and itemssold are 4th and 5th columns in your data file.

Comment: dump b; looks like below,

Chicago,12
Dallas,20
Atlanta,22
Chicago,23
Atlanta,12
Dallas,87
..... so on.

Yes i am aware that indexes starts at $0 position. They are at 4th and 5th position respectively.

Comment: Try c = GROUP b BY b.city; d = FOREACH c GENERATE b.city, AVG(b.itemssold);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data contains some missing value, try filtering it first like this:

```
no_nulls = FILTER b BY itemssold is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = LOAD 'sales.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
b = FOREACH a GENERATE (chararray) $3 as city, (int) $4 as itemssold;
c = GROUP b BY city; 
d = FOREACH c GENERATE group,AVG(b.itemssold); 
dump d;
```

The above code worked. In the relation b GENERATE, i was trying to define the schema rather than casting, hence pig got confused. Corrected that now & it worked. Thanks all for your suggestions.